# How to make a pyparsing grammar dependent on an instance attribute?

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, string-parsing, pyparsing

I’ve got a pyparsing issue that I have spent days trying to fix, with no luck.

Here’s the relevant pseudocode:

```
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.multilineCommands = []
        self.grammar = <pyparsing grammar> # depends on self.multilineCommands
```

So, I’m trying to get a specific set of doctests to pass.  But the tests in question update `self.multilineCommands` after instantiation.  Although there are no issues setting the attribute correctly, `self.grammar` seems blind to the change, and fails the tests.

However, if I set `self.multilineCommands` inside `__init__()`, then the tests all pass.

How can I get `self.grammar` to stay up-to-date with `self.multilineCommands`?

## Follow-Up

So, part of the issue here is that I’m refactoring code I didn’t write.  My experience with pyparsing is also exclusively limited to my work on this project.

Pyparsing author Paul McGuire posted a helpful response, but I couldn’t get it to work. It could be an error on my part, but more likely the bigger issue is that I over-simplified the pseudo-code written above.

So, I’m going to post the actual code.

#### Warning!

What you are about to see is uncensored. The sight of it might make you cringe…or maybe even cry.  In the original module, this code was just a *single* piece of a total “god class”.  Splitting out what is below into the `Parser` class is just step 1 (and apparently, step 1 was enough to break the tests).

---

```
class Parser(object):
    '''Container object pyparsing-related parsing.
    '''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        r'''
        >>> c = Cmd()
        >>> c.multilineCommands = ['multiline']
        >>> c.multilineCommands
        ['multiline']
        >>> c.parser.multilineCommands
        ['multiline']
        >>> c.case_insensitive = True
        >>> c.case_insensitive
        True
        >>> c.parser.case_insensitive
        True
        >>> print (c.parser('').dump())
        []
        >>> print (c.parser('/* empty command */').dump())
        []
        >>> print (c.parser('plainword').dump())
        ['plainword', '']
        - command: plainword
        - statement: ['plainword', '']
          - command: plainword
        >>> print (c.parser('termbare;').dump())
        ['termbare', '', ';', '']
        - command: termbare
        - statement: ['termbare', '', ';']
          - command: termbare
          - terminator: ;
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('termbare; suffx').dump())
        ['termbare', '', ';', 'suffx']
        - command: termbare
        - statement: ['termbare', '', ';']
          - command: termbare
          - terminator: ;
        - suffix: suffx
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('barecommand').dump())
        ['barecommand', '']
        - command: barecommand
        - statement: ['barecommand', '']
          - command: barecommand
        >>> print (c.parser('COMmand with args').dump())
        ['command', 'with args']
        - args: with args
        - command: command
        - statement: ['command', 'with args']
          - args: with args
          - command: command
        >>> print (c.parser('command with args and terminator; and suffix').dump())
        ['command', 'with args and terminator', ';', 'and suffix']
        - args: with args and terminator
        - command: command
        - statement: ['command', 'with args and terminator', ';']
          - args: with args and terminator
          - command: command
          - terminator: ;
        - suffix: and suffix
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('simple | piped').dump())
        ['simple', '', '|', ' piped']
        - command: simple
        - pipeTo:  piped
        - statement: ['simple', '']
          - command: simple
        >>> print (c.parser('double-pipe || is not a pipe').dump())
        ['double', '-pipe || is not a pipe']
        - args: -pipe || is not a pipe
        - command: double
        - statement: ['double', '-pipe || is not a pipe']
          - args: -pipe || is not a pipe
          - command: double
        >>> print (c.parser('command with args, terminator;sufx | piped').dump())
        ['command', 'with args, terminator', ';', 'sufx', '|', ' piped']
        - args: with args, terminator
        - command: command
        - pipeTo:  piped
        - statement: ['command', 'with args, terminator', ';']
          - args: with args, terminator
          - command: command
          - terminator: ;
        - suffix: sufx
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('output into > afile.txt').dump())
        ['output', 'into', '>', 'afile.txt']
        - args: into
        - command: output
        - output: >
        - outputTo: afile.txt
        - statement: ['output', 'into']
          - args: into
          - command: output
        >>> print (c.parser('output into;sufx | pipethrume plz > afile.txt').dump())
        ['output', 'into', ';', 'sufx', '|', ' pipethrume plz', '>', 'afile.txt']
        - args: into
        - command: output
        - output: >
        - outputTo: afile.txt
        - pipeTo:  pipethrume plz
        - statement: ['output', 'into', ';']
          - args: into
          - command: output
          - terminator: ;
        - suffix: sufx
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('output to paste buffer >> ').dump())
        ['output', 'to paste buffer', '>>', '']
        - args: to paste buffer
        - command: output
        - output: >>
        - statement: ['output', 'to paste buffer']
          - args: to paste buffer
          - command: output
        >>> print (c.parser('ignore the /* commented | > */ stuff;').dump())
        ['ignore', 'the /* commented | > */ stuff', ';', '']
        - args: the /* commented | > */ stuff
        - command: ignore
        - statement: ['ignore', 'the /* commented | > */ stuff', ';']
          - args: the /* commented | > */ stuff
          - command: ignore
          - terminator: ;
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('has > inside;').dump())
        ['has', '> inside', ';', '']
        - args: > inside
        - command: has
        - statement: ['has', '> inside', ';']
          - args: > inside
          - command: has
          - terminator: ;
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('multiline has > inside an unfinished command').dump())
        ['multiline', ' has > inside an unfinished command']
        - multilineCommand: multiline
        >>> print (c.parser('multiline has > inside;').dump())
        ['multiline', 'has > inside', ';', '']
        - args: has > inside
        - multilineCommand: multiline
        - statement: ['multiline', 'has > inside', ';']
          - args: has > inside
          - multilineCommand: multiline
          - terminator: ;
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('multiline command /* with comment in progress;').dump())
        ['multiline', ' command /* with comment in progress;']
        - multilineCommand: multiline
        >>> print (c.parser('multiline command /* with comment complete */ is done;').dump())
        ['multiline', 'command /* with comment complete */ is done', ';', '']
        - args: command /* with comment complete */ is done
        - multilineCommand: multiline
        - statement: ['multiline', 'command /* with comment complete */ is done', ';']
          - args: command /* with comment complete */ is done
          - multilineCommand: multiline
          - terminator: ;
        - terminator: ;
        >>> print (c.parser('multiline command ends\n\n').dump())
        ['multiline', 'command ends', '\n', '\n']
        - args: command ends
        - multilineCommand: multiline
        - statement: ['multiline', 'command ends', '\n', '\n']
          - args: command ends
          - multilineCommand: multiline
          - terminator: ['\n', '\n']
        - terminator: ['\n', '\n']
        >>> print (c.parser('multiline command "with term; ends" now\n\n').dump())
        ['multiline', 'command "with term; ends" now', '\n', '\n']
        - args: command "with term; ends" now
        - multilineCommand: multiline
        - statement: ['multiline', 'command "with term; ends" now', '\n', '\n']
          - args: command "with term; ends" now
          - multilineCommand: multiline
          - terminator: ['\n', '\n']
        - terminator: ['\n', '\n']
        >>> print (c.parser('what if "quoted strings /* seem to " start comments?').dump())
        ['what', 'if "quoted strings /* seem to " start comments?']
        - args: if "quoted strings /* seem to " start comments?
        - command: what
        - statement: ['what', 'if "quoted strings /* seem to " start comments?']
          - args: if "quoted strings /* seem to " start comments?
          - command: what
        '''

        #   SETTINGS
        self._init_settings()

        #   GRAMMAR
        self._init_grammars()

        #   PARSERS

        #   For easy reference to all contained parsers.
        #   Hacky, I know.  But I'm trying to fix code
        #   elsewhere at the moment... :P)
        self._parsers = set()

        self._init_prefixParser()
        self._init_terminatorParser()
        self._init_saveParser()
        self._init_inputParser()
        self._init_outputParser()

        #   intermission!  :D
        #   (update grammar(s) containing parsers)
        self.afterElements = \
            pyparsing.Optional(self.pipe         + pyparsing.SkipTo(self.outputParser ^ self.stringEnd, ignore=self.doNotParse)('pipeTo')) + \
            pyparsing.Optional(self.outputParser('output') + pyparsing.SkipTo(self.stringEnd,                     ignore=self.doNotParse).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('outputTo'))
        self._grammars.add('afterElements')
        #   end intermission

        self._init_blankLineTerminationParser()
        self._init_multilineParser()
        self._init_singleLineParser()
        self._init_optionParser()

        #   Put it all together:
        self.mainParser = \
                        ( self.prefixParser       +
                            (   self.stringEnd                  |
                                self.multilineParser            |
                                self.singleLineParser           |
                                self.blankLineTerminationParser |
                                self.multilineCommand   + pyparsing.SkipTo(
                                    self.stringEnd,
                                    ignore=self.doNotParse)
                            )
                        )
        self.mainParser.ignore(self.commentGrammars)
        #self.mainParser.setDebug(True)
        #   And we've got mainParser.

    #
    #   SPECIAL METHODS
    #
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Call an instance for convenient parsing.  Example:

                p = Parser()
                result = p('some stuff for p to parse')

            This just calls `self.parseString()`, so it's safe to
            override should you choose.
        '''
        return self.parseString(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        #   REMEMBER: This is only called when normal attribute lookup fails
        raise AttributeError('Could not find {0!r} in class Parser'.format(attr))

    @property
    def multilineCommands(self):
        return self._multilineCommands

    @multilineCommands.setter
    def multilineCommands(self, value):
        value = list(value) if not isinstance(value, list) else value
        self._multilineCommands = value

    @multilineCommands.deleter
    def multilineCommands(self):
        del self._multilineCommands
        self._multilineCommands = []

    #
    #   PSEUDO_PRIVATE METHODS
    #
    def _init_settings(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._multilineCommands  = []

        self.abbrev             = True     # recognize abbreviated commands
        self.blankLinesAllowed  = False
        self.case_insensitive   = True
        self.identchars         = cmd.IDENTCHARS
        self.legalChars         = u'!#$%.:?@_' + pyparsing.alphanums + pyparsing.alphas8bit
        self.noSpecialParse     = {'ed','edit','exit','set'}
        self.redirector         = '>'      # for sending output to file
        self.reserved_words     = []
        self.shortcuts          = {'?' : 'help' ,
                                   '!' : 'shell',
                                   '@' : 'load' ,
                                   '@@': '_relative_load'}
        self.terminators        = [';']
        self.keywords           = [] + self.reserved_words

    def _init_grammars(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #   Basic grammars
        self.commentGrammars    =   (pyparsing.pythonStyleComment|pyparsing.cStyleComment).ignore(pyparsing.quotedString).suppress()
        self.commentInProgress  =   '/*' + pyparsing.SkipTo( pyparsing.stringEnd ^ '*/' )
        self.doNotParse         =   self.commentGrammars | self.commentInProgress | pyparsing.quotedString
        self.fileName           =   pyparsing.Word(self.legalChars + '/\\')
        self.inputFrom          =   self.fileName('inputFrom')
        self.inputMark          =   pyparsing.Literal('<')
        self.pipe               =   pyparsing.Keyword('|', identChars='|')
        self.stringEnd          =   pyparsing.stringEnd ^ '\nEOF'
        #   Complex grammars
        self.multilineCommand   =   pyparsing.Or([pyparsing.Keyword(c, caseless=self.case_insensitive) for c in self.multilineCommands ])('multilineCommand')
        self.multilineCommand.setName('multilineCommand')
        self.oneLineCommand     =   ( ~self.multilineCommand + pyparsing.Word(self.legalChars))('command')

        #   Hack-y convenience access to grammars
        self._grammars = {
             #   Basic grammars
             'commentGrammars',
             'commentInProgress',
             'doNotParse',
             'fileName',
             'inputFrom',
             'inputMark',
             'noSpecialParse',
             'pipe',
             'reserved_words',
             'stringEnd',
             #   Complex grammars
             'multilineCommand',
             'oneLineCommand'
         }

        self.inputFrom.setParseAction(replace_with_file_contents)
        self.inputMark.setParseAction(lambda x: '')
        self.commentGrammars.addParseAction(lambda x: '')

        if not self.blankLinesAllowed:
            self.blankLineTerminator = (pyparsing.lineEnd * 2)('terminator')

        if self.case_insensitive:
            self.multilineCommand.setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].lower())
            self.oneLineCommand.setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].lower())

    def _init_all_parsers(self):
        self._init_prefixParser()
        self._init_terminatorParser()
        self._init_saveParser()
        self._init_inputParser()
        self._init_outputParser()

        #   intermission!  :D
        #   (update grammar(s) containing parsers)
        self.afterElements = \
            pyparsing.Optional(self.pipe         + pyparsing.SkipTo(self.outputParser ^ self.stringEnd, ignore=self.doNotParse)('pipeTo')) + \
            pyparsing.Optional(self.outputParser('output') + pyparsing.SkipTo(self.stringEnd,                     ignore=self.doNotParse).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('outputTo'))
        self._grammars.setName('afterElements')
        self._grammars.add('afterElements')
        #   end intermission

        # FIXME:
        #   For some reason it's necessary to set this again.
        #   (Otherwise pyparsing results include `outputTo`, but not `output`.)
        self.outputParser('output')

        self._init_blankLineTerminationParser()
        self._init_multilineParser()
        self._init_singleLineParser()
        self._init_optionParser()

    def _init_prefixParser(self):
        self.prefixParser     = pyparsing.Empty()
        self.prefixParser.setName('prefixParser')
        self._parsers.add('prefixParser')

    def _init_terminatorParser(self):
        self.terminatorParser = pyparsing.Or([ (hasattr(t, 'parseString') and t) or pyparsing.Literal(t) for t in self.terminators])('terminator')
        self.terminatorParser.setName('terminatorParser')
        self._parsers.add('terminatorParser')

    def _init_saveParser(self):
        self.saveparser = (pyparsing.Optional(pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums)|'*')('idx')        +
                           pyparsing.Optional(pyparsing.Word(self.legalChars + '/\\'))('fname') +
                           pyparsing.stringEnd)
        self.saveparser.setName('saveParser')
        self._parsers.add('saveParser')

    def _init_outputParser(self):
        # outputParser = (pyparsing.Literal('>>') | (pyparsing.WordStart() + '>') | pyparsing.Regex('[^=]>'))('output')
        self.outputParser   =  self.redirector * 2 | (pyparsing.WordStart()  + self.redirector) | pyparsing.Regex('[^=]' + self.redirector)('output')
        self.outputParser.setName('outputParser')
        self._parsers.add('outputParser')

    def _init_inputParser(self):
        # a not-entirely-satisfactory way of distinguishing < as in "import from" from <
        # as in "lesser than"
        self.inputParser = self.inputMark         + \
               pyparsing.Optional(self.inputFrom) + \
               pyparsing.Optional('>')            + \
               pyparsing.Optional(self.fileName)  + \
               (pyparsing.stringEnd | '|')
        self.inputParser.ignore(self.commentInProgress)
        self.inputParser.setName('inputParser')
        self._parsers.add('inputParser')

    def _init_blankLineTerminationParser(self):
        self.blankLineTerminationParser = pyparsing.NoMatch

        if not self.blankLinesAllowed:
            self.blankLineTerminationParser = ((self.multilineCommand ^ self.oneLineCommand) + pyparsing.SkipTo(self.blankLineTerminator, ignore=self.doNotParse).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('args') + self.blankLineTerminator )

        #   FIXME:  Does this call *really* have to be reassigned into the variable???
        self.blankLineTerminationParser = self.blankLineTerminationParser.setResultsName('statement')
        self.blankLineTerminationParser.setName('blankLineTerminationParser')
        self._parsers.add('blankLineTerminationParser')

    def _init_multilineParser(self):
        #self.multilineParser  = self.multilineParser.setResultsName('multilineParser')
        self.multilineParser = (
            (
                (self.multilineCommand('multilineCommand') ^ self.oneLineCommand)
                +   pyparsing.SkipTo(self.terminatorParser, ignore=self.doNotParse).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('args')
                +   self.terminatorParser
            )('statement')
            + pyparsing.SkipTo(
                self.outputParser ^ self.pipe ^ self.stringEnd, ignore=self.doNotParse
                ).setParseAction(lambda x: x[0].strip())('suffix')
            + self.afterElements)
        self.multilineParser.ignore(self.commentInProgress)
        self.multilineParser.setName('multilineParser')
        self._parsers.add('multilineParser')

    def _init_singleLineParser(self):
        #self.singleLineParser = self.singleLineParser.setResultsName('singleLineParser')
        self.singleLineParser = ((self.oneLineCommand + pyparsing.SkipTo(self.terminatorParser ^ self.stringEnd ^ self.pipe ^ self.outputParser, ignore=self.doNotParse).setParseAction(lambda x:x[0].strip())('args'))('statement') +
                                 pyparsing.Optional(self.terminatorParser) + self.afterElements)
        self.singleLineParser.setName('singleLineParser')
        self._parsers.add('singleLineParser')

    def _init_optionParser(self):
        #   Different from the other parsers.
        #   This one is based on optparse.OptionParser,
        #   not pyparsing.
        #
        #   It's included here to keep all parsing-related
        #   code under one roof.

        # TODO: Why isn't this using cmd2's OptionParser?
        self.optionParser = optparse.OptionParser()
        self._parsers.add('optionParser')

    def parseString(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Parses a string using `self.mainParser`.'''
        return self.mainParser.parseString(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

There you have it.  The ugly truth. ☺

**Edited 2012-11-12:** I incorrectly used the term “class attribute” in the original title for this question.  It‘s a silly mistake, and I apologize for any confusion.  It has now been corrected to “instance attribute”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `self.multilineCommands` as a Forward, like this:

```
self.multlineCommands = Forward()
```

and then define the rest of your grammar using `self.multilineCommands` as you would normally. In your tests, “inject” different expressions for `self.multilineCommands` using the `<<` operator:

```
self.multilineCommands << (test expression 1)
```

Then when you parse using the overall grammar, your pyparsing test expression will be used where ever `self.multilineCommands` is.

(**Note:**
Be sure to enclose the right-hand side in `()`’s to guard against precedence of operations problems due to my unfortunate choice of `<<` for this operator. In the next release of pyparsing, I’ll add support for `<<=` and deprecate `<<` for this operation, which will resolve most of this problem.)

**EDIT**
Here is a flexible parser that has a write-only property that will accept a list of strings to take as allowed keywords. The parser itself is a simple function call parser that parses functions that take a single numeric argument, or the constants `pi` or `π` or `e`.

```
# coding=UTF-8
from pyparsing import *

class FlexParser(object):
    def __init__(self, fixedPart):
        self._dynamicExpr = Forward()
        self.parser = self._dynamicExpr + fixedPart

    def _set_keywords(self, kw_list):
        # accept a list of words, convert it to a MatchFirst of
        # Keywords defined using those words
        self._dynamicExpr << (MatchFirst(map(Keyword, kw_list)))
    keywords = property(fset=_set_keywords)

    def parseString(self,s):
        return self.parser.parseString(s)

E  = CaselessKeyword("e").setParseAction(replaceWith(2.71828))
PI = (CaselessKeyword("pi") | "π").setParseAction(replaceWith(3.14159))
numericLiteral = PI | E | Regex(r'[+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))
fp = FlexParser('(' + numericLiteral + ')')
fp.keywords = "sin cos tan asin acos atan sqrt".split()

print fp.parseString("sin(30)")
print fp.parseString("cos(π)")
print fp.parseString("sqrt(-1)")
```

Now change the keywords by just assigning a word list to the `keywords` property. The setter method converts the list to a MatchFirst of Keywords. Note that now, parsing "sin(30)" will raise an exception:

```
fp.keywords = "foo bar baz boo".split()
print fp.parseString("foo(1000)")
print fp.parseString("baz(e)")
print fp.parseString("bar(1729)")
print fp.parseString("sin(30)")   # raises a ParseException
```

Comment: my favorite feature of pyparsing is your unbelievably awesome support!  This is the second time I’ve posted a question about pyparsing which you have answered in just a few hours.  How many other  packages have an author like that?  ☺ <br>  I’ll let you know how it goes…

Comment: Hmm…still can’t get it to work.  Admittedly I’m not sure if I’m “doing it right”, but it could also be a dozen other things.  The real code is obviously much tricker than the pseudocode I wrote in the original question.  I’ll go ahead and post a follow-up with the actual code and hopefully it it will make sense.

Comment: I don't see where you are using `Forward` or `<<` in your posted code, nor do I see where multilineCommands is a class attribute. I'll edit my answer to show you a simple example of a modifiable class attribute that will modify a parser placeholder created using a Forward. Also, you seem to be assigning lists of words in your grammar - you have to convert that into a pyparsing expression.

Comment: Ah...I didn’t fully explain myself.  (1) Regarding `Forward` and `<<`: when the tests still didn’t pass, I assumed it was because I didn’t use it properly, so I undid the changes.  (2) Regarding the class attribute, I simply misused the term “class attribute”.  I meant instance attribute.  I feel pretty silly about these mistakes, and I apologize for the confusion.  (I’ll edit the question’s title to prevent the confusion of other readers.)

Comment: I just tried again, using your edited-in `FlexParser` example.  That solved the issue!  Having that example was really helpful in understanding how to use `Forward` and `<<`.  Thanks so much!  :D

Answer (score -1):

If you want `self.grammar` to always be equal to `self.multilineCommands` it is as simple as:

```
self.multilineCommands=['hello','world','multiline']
self.grammar=self.multilineCommands
```

Then you could change either value and they will both be the same.

Comment: That won’t work.  :( I need it to be a **pyparsing** grammar—not a regular list.